# tableView:heightOfRow: never called

Tags: cocoa, nstableview

I'm trying to get a row in my table view to resize its height, but the delegate method:

`- (CGFloat) tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView heightOfRow:(NSInteger)row`

is never called. I have implemented other delegate methods and they work perfectly.
Is there something I am not doing?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you confirm that you've implemented other *delegate* methods and not other *datasource* methods? A common error is to hook up your datasource but not your delegate. They're different outlets on an NSTableView.

Comment: Ooooh, wow. I should have checked that more carefully. Thank you, I was confused about it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Are you changing the row heights? From the docs:

> Although table views may cache the returned values, you should ensure that this method is efficient. When you change a row's height you must invalidate the existing row height by calling `noteHeightOfRowsWithIndexesChanged:`. NSTableView automatically invalidates its entire row height cache when `reloadData` and `noteNumberOfRowsChanged` are called.